# Ervah in front of mezuzot

Tags: tznius-modesty, mezuzah, kavod, home-house, holy-objects

Does one need to remain fully covered when there is a mezuzah in view? I am asking based on the principle of koved seforim, according to which, as I understand it, one may not expose ervah to (uncovered) holy books and other holy items.

I understand the mezuzah is already covered once by a case, but two covers are preferred by many ( http://gt.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5774/vayechi.html , inter alia); also, I worry that the /shin/ on the outside of the mezuzah case is a Shem Hashem (or close enough) before which one should not be uncovered.

Practically speaking, the requirement I'm asking about would--I think--mean only changing clothes, etc., in the most distal rooms of the house--and maybe not even in these, if the mezuze is inside the door--or in bathrooms, and always with the door closed. Is this how it is?

Comment: Note also the ambiguity in the word _erva_. It also means ~"a relative one is forbidden to marry".

Comment: Are you referring to the ש on the outside being an abbreviation of שד-י?

Comment: @WAF yes (char)

Comment: Is it? (indeed)

Answer (score 2):

One does need to remain fully covered in front of a *mezuzah*, as it would not be respectful to the *mezuzah* to stand naked before it. Where there is filth, such as children (presumably babies and very young children who don't know how to stay clean), it is good that the *mezuzah* be covered ([YD 286:2,5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6801)).

The Taz ([YD 286:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6801)), Aruch HaShulchan ([YD 286:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%99)), and the Ben Ish Chai write that a glass covering is not sufficient for *ervah*.

Comment: @Pioni Thanks. What about the issue of the 'shin' on the mezuze?

Comment: @SAH I haven't seen that anywhere, but in any case that is written on the cover of the mezuza whereas in your scenario you would have to put a second covering on so it would anyway be covered (albeit not with a double covering).