# Must tashmish at night be under a blanket?

Tags: sexuality, kavod, holy-objects

From [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22092/tashmish-ha-mitah-byom-marital-relations-by-day) it seems that relations by day must be under a blanket (e.g. a *tallis*). But, at night, is it necessary that the couple be covered, or is this a *chumra* (i.e. stringency)?

What if there are uncovered holy books, mezuzos, or other holy objects in the room?

If blankets are necessary, can a canopy bed do the same job?

Comment: Voted to close as these subjects are best discussed _in private_ with a competent, Orthodox rabbi.

Comment: This is a huge mix of subjects - where the final decision is a trade-off between them. 1. **Tzniut* - one should feel the presence of the divine spirit (שכינה) and therefore even at night, a blanket/canopy should be used. BTW the books and other holy object are "personification" of that spirit. 2. Health issues 3. Intention - many reasons (such as Shlom Bayt by either side) might override #1 (if not open parchment texts), for example, if the wife refuses to do otherwise.

Comment: For topics such as these,"Halachic Positions " is a good book with many sources

Comment: I was thinking about this based on your related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73803/ervah-in-front-of-mezuzot

Comment: There are two independent issues. The first is the tsniut, regarding night and covering bodies. The second is mechitsa between intercourse place and Holly books.

Comment: For instance to urinate naked at night near to the bed is unadvised. The concept of חדרי חדרים is not linked to the possibility that someone will see, but the as if someone will see. Regarding seforim they need two covering or to be in a separate place

Comment: I think the part about mezuzos and seforim should be removed. If this question is about not using a blanket, then focus on permissibility of the act itself.

Answer (score 3):

Elements for answer

**Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 40: 2 regarding tefilin and mezuzah at home.**

> בית שיש בו תפילין אסור לשמש בו מטתו עד שיוציאם או שיניחם בכלי תוך כלי והוא שאין השני מיוחד להם שאם הוא מיוחד אפילו מאה חשובים כאחד.‏
>
> הגה: ואם שניהם אינם מיוחדים להם או שהפנימי אינו מיוחד להם והחיצון מיוחד להם מותר (ועיין לקמן סימן ר"מ סעיף ו') (בית יוסף):‏

It's not allowed to have an intimate relationship in home. When tefilin are there. But if tefilin are inside two bags, almost one of them need to bee not specifically a tefilin bag. For mezuzah the din is the same.

**240:6**

> בית שיש ספר תורה או חומשים העשוים בגלילה אסור לשמש בו עד שיהיה בפניו מחיצה (ולענין לעשותה בשבת עיין לקמן ריש סימן שט"ו) ואם יש לו בית אחר אסור עד שיוציאנה ואם יש בו תפילין או ספרים אפילו של גמרא אסור עד שיתנם בכלי בתוך כלי והוא שלא יהא השני מיוחד להם (ועיין לעיל סימן מ' סעיף ב') אבל אם הוא מיוחד להם אפילו מאה כחד חשיבי ואם פירש טלית ע"ג ארגז חשוב ככלי בתוך כלי:‏

Gemarot and Holly books are included.

**240:11**

> אסור לשמש לאור הנר אע"פ שמאפיל בטליתו:‏
>
> הגה: אבל אם עושה מחיצה גבוה עשרה לפני הנר (הגהות מיימוני פ"ד מהל' י"ט) אע"פ שהאור נראה דרך המחיצה כגון שהפסיק בסדין שרי (כן נראה לי מדברי רש"י בפ"ב דמסכת ביצה) גם אמרינן התם דשרי כשכופה כלי על הנר ואם מותר לעשות מחיצה זו בשבת ע"ל ריש סי' שט"ו:
> וכן אסור לשמש ביום אלא אם כן הוא בית אפל:
> ‏
> הגה: ותלמיד חכם מאפיל בטליתו ושרי (טור):
>
> (לו) וצריך וכו' - כתבו התוספות [נדה י"ז] בשם המדרש דהקב"ה שונא המשמש ערום. ודוקא ערום ממש ומשום דיש לו לאדם להיות צנוע אבל אם מכסה עצמו מלמעלה ליכא שום חשש בדבר:
> ‏

There is a function of Talith against day's light

**1:1 in Rema**

> כי אין ישיבת האדם ותנועותיו ועסקיו והוא לבדו בביתו, כישיבתו ותנועותיו ועסקיו והוא לפני מלך גדול; ולא דיבורו והרחבת פיו כרצונו, והוא עם אנשי ביתו וקרוביו, כדיבורו במושב המלך. כל שכן, כשישים האדם אל ליבו שהמלך הגדול, הקב"ה אשר מלא כל הארץ כבודו, עומד עליו ורואה במעשיו, כמו שנאמר: "אם יסתר איש במסתרים ואני לא אראנו נאם ה'", מיד יגיע אליו היראה וההכנעה בפחד השי"ת ובושתו ממנו תמיד (מורה נבוכים ח"ג פ' נ"ב).‏

Shame d/t "presence of" g-d ideally has to be equivalent to shame d/t presence of a person

**240:8, Mishna Berura sk 36** in name of Tosfot quoting Midrash

(לו) וצריך וכו' - כתבו התוספות [נדה י"ז] בשם המדרש דהקב"ה שונא המשמש ערום. ודוקא ערום ממש ומשום דיש לו לאדם להיות צנוע אבל אם מכסה עצמו מלמעלה ליכא שום חשש בדבר:‏

Hakadosh Baruch Hu hates persons who make tashmish naked but covered (with a blanket) is not as if they are naked.

Comment: Check Berakhot 23b-24a

Comment: I know... From the Gemara

Comment: @kouty how does the medresh know that gd hates those that have relations without being covered? Also, does that mean it's mandatory?

Comment: What's considered not covered

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here ([Nedorim 20b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nedarim.20b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), also see Rashi on "וכשהוא מספר") - the Gemmorah presents two opposite approaches:

> (1) "אמרה להן אינו מספר עמי לא בתחלת הלילה ולא בסוף הלילה אלא בחצות הלילה **וכשהוא מספר מגלה טפח ומכסה טפח ודומה עליו כמי שכפאו שד** ואמרתי לו מה טעם ואמר לי כדי שלא אתן את עיני באשה אחרת ונמצאו בניו באין לידי ממזרות לא קשיא הא במילי דתשמיש הא במילי אחרנייתא
>
> (2)אמר רבי יוחנן זו דברי יוחנן בן דהבאי **אבל אמרו חכמים אין הלכה כיוחנן בן דהבאי אלא כל מה שאדם רוצה לעשות באשתו עושה** משל לבשר הבא מבית הטבח רצה לאכלו במלח אוכלו צלי אוכלו מבושל אוכלו שלוק אוכלו וכן דג הבא מבית הצייד "
>
> (1)"...She said to them: My husband does not converse with me while engaging in sexual intercourse, neither at the beginning of the night nor at the end of the night, but rather at midnight. And when he converses with me while engaging in sexual intercourse, he reveals a handbreadth of my body and covers a handbreadth, and **he covers himself up as though he were being coerced by a demon and is covering himself out of fear**...
>
> (2) Rabbi Yoḥanan said: ... Rather, whatever a man wishes to do with his wife he may do. He may engage in sexual intercourse with her in any manner that he wishes, and need not concern himself with these restrictions. As an allegory, it is like meat that comes from the butcher. If he wants to eat it with salt, he may eat it that way. If he wants to eat it roasted, he may eat it roasted. If he wants to eat it cooked, he may eat it cooked. If he wants to eat it boiled, he may eat it boiled. And likewise with regard to fish that come from the fisherman.  "

Traditionally, **every religious community has its own rules and regulations anywhere between those two approaches**.